# How to join 2 tables based on passing a parameter for search operation?

Tags: java, jpa, join, criteria-api

I have 2 entities Addemp and Job.I want to join these 2 tables based on empid .empid is foreign key in job table and primary key in addemp table

here i am doing a search operation based on employee id .i am using criteria builder for search operation

the relationship here is manytoone

```
 public List<Object[]> findEmployeeList(Integer id)
{
    EntityManager em=null;
    try
    {

        em=getEntityManager();
          CriteriaBuilder cb=em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery cq=cb.createQuery(Addemp.class);
        Root<Addemp>rt= cq.from(Addemp.class);
        Join<Addemp,Job> job=rt.join(Addemp_.jobCollection);
        Predicate predicate=cb.equal(rt.get("empId"),id);
        cq.where(predicate);



       /* cq.select(rt.get("firstName"));
        cq.where (cb.equal(rt.<String>get("empId"),id));*/
         Query qry= em.createQuery(cq);
    return qry.getResultList();
```

Comment: what is your question? The query looks okay. You can use TypedQuery at the end: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html

Comment: actually i am displaying the contents using DataModel and my code looks like this                                                         <p:dataTable value="#{coemp.empapp.empSearchModel}"  var="rec" paginator="true" rows="2">
                 <p:column headerText="Employee id">
                     <h:outputText value="#{rec[0]}"/>
                </p:column>
                  <p:column headerText="Employee Status">
                     <h:outputText value="#{rec[1]}"/>
                </p:column>

Comment: public DataModel getEmpSearchModel() {
       if(empSearchModel==null){
           empSearchModel=performEmpSearch();
         
       }
      return empSearchModel;
    }
    public String getEmpRecord()
    {
        empSearchModel=getEmpSearchModel();
        empSearchModel.toString();
        return "added";
    }

Comment: i am not able to display the contents empid which is in addemp table and emp_status which is in job table   kindly help me out guys

Comment: Use TypedQuery "TypedQuery<Addemp> typed = em.createQuery(cq);
        return typed.getResultList();" than you have your object and you can work with it over point operator. Your method should look like:  public List<Addemp> findEmployeeList(Integer id) .Look primcefaces showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableBasic.jsf how to access a pojo.

Comment: i got my object as u said but what i have done is                          public DataModel performEmpSearch()
   {
       Integer id=emp.getEmpId();
       String empname=emp.getFirstName();
//       String ln=emp.getLastName();
 //      String job_title=job.getJobTitle();
 //      String emp_status=job.getEmpStatus();

   
       return new ListDataModel(serv.searchEmp(id));
        }                                                                     public List<Object[]> searchEmp(Integer id){
          initEmpJpa();
             return   EmpJp.findEmployeeList(id);
       }

Comment: As far as I can see you want to retrieve `empid` and `emp_status` columns from two seperate tables at once, therefore I would like to suggest you replacing `select()` with `multiselect()` in the query. Of course `CriteriaQuery<T>` and `TypedQuery<T>` will change their type parameters then (either `Tuple` or `Object[]` - depends on your preferences).

Comment: since i am new to jpa joins plz help me out by example of my query              em=getEntityManager();
              CriteriaBuilder cb=em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery cq=cb.createQuery(Addemp.class);
            Root<Addemp>rt= cq.from(Addemp.class);
            Join<Addemp,Job> job=rt.join(Addemp_.jobCollection);
             cq.multiselect(rt.get("empId"),rt.get("empStatus"));
             Predicate predicate=cb.equal(rt.get("empId"),id);
             cq.where(predicate);

Comment: @user3227175: Did you try to build your query with JPQL or SQL? Just for quick prototyping and making sure that your persistence model (entities, relationships) is working as expected?

Comment: @wypieprz:i tried using jpql my query is working fine in mysql here is my jpql query which i have written query="Select a.empId,a.firstName,a.lastName,j.jobTitle,j.empStatus,j.subUnit"+
           "FROM Job j,Addemp a"+
           "WHERE a.empId = j.empId"                                    the main thing is that i am doing a search operation that must be performed on 2 tables help me out

Comment: @user3227175: What you are actually trying to do in JPQL is _cartesian join_ between `Addemp` and `Job` entities, however the code snipped from the question makes _inner join_ between them. Which one is proper then?

Comment: @wypieprz:my main aim is to do search operation from both the Addemp and Job tables by passing parameters .i tried it both usin criteria builder and jpql .firstly i am doing search operation based on empid which is fk in job and pk in addemp table then i want to do search based on other parameters as well.plz help me out

Comment: @user3227175: I am still not sure what result are you expecting from your query, but the answer is: in case of _cartesian join_ you have to use two roots in your Criteria API (`Root<Addemp>` and `Root<Job>`), in case of _inner join_ you have to use one root and then join in your Criteria API (`Root<Addemp>` and `Join<Addemp, Job>`) just like you did in the code snippet. Note that these two will give you different results.

Comment: @wypieprz:Is this query correct                                             CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
             CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(Addemp.class);
             Root<Addemp> EmpRoot = cq.from(Addemp.class);
             Root<Job>JobRoot=cq.from(Job.class);
             cq.select(EmpRoot.get("empId"));
             cq.select(JobRoot.get("empId"));
             cq.where(cb.equal(EmpRoot.<String>get("empId"), id));
            
            TypedQuery qr1 = em.createQuery(cq);

            return qr1.getResultList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question and JPQL query from the above comments here is the criteria query proposal:

```java
public List<Tuple> findEmployeeList(Integer id)
{
    em = getEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();
    Root<Addemp> empRoot = cq.from(Addemp.class);
    Root<Job> jobRoot = cq.from(Job.class);
    cq.multiselect(empRoot.get("empId").alias("id"), 
                   empRoot.get("firstName").alias("first"),
                   empRoot.get("lastName").alias("last"),
                   jobRoot.get("jobTitle").alias("title"),
                   jobRoot.get("empStatus").alias("status"),
                   jobRoot.get("subUnit").alias("subunit"));
    cq.where(cb.equal(empRoot.get("empId"), id));

    TypedQuery<Tuple> q = em.createQuery(cq);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

Next you may want to extract a tuple result:

```java
List<Tuple> tuples = service.findEmployeeList(2);
for (Tuple t : tuples) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(64)
        .append(t.get("id")).append(", ")
        .append(t.get("first")).append(", ")
        .append(t.get("last")).append(", ")
        .append(t.get("title")).append(", ")
        .append(t.get("status")).append(", ")
        .append(t.get("subunit"));
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: :i have 3 packages service,application,controller within jpa contoller i have written your criteria query which is in service package then within service package i have class called EmpService i am just calling a jpacontroller method EmployeeList like this   public List<Tuple> searchEmp(int id){
          initEmpJpa();
             return   EmpJp.findEmployeeList(id);
       }

Comment: :then again in EmpApp class i need get the values            public String getEmpRecords()
    {
        List<Tuple> tuples = serv.searchEmp(2);
for (Tuple t : tuples) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(64)
        .append(t.get("id")).append(", ")
        .append(t.get("first")).append(", ")
        .append(t.get("last")).append(", ")
        .append(t.get("title")).append(", ");
       .append(t.get("status")).append(", ");
       .append(t.get("subunit"));
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
}        return null;
 }  but illegal start of expression error

Comment: _Illegal start of expression_ is related to compilation error. I think you need to remove a semicolon in `append(", ");` methods because all of them are part of a single command so only one semicolon is required at the end.

Comment: the query is working fine how to iterate it jsf page and display it in h:datatable  i tried it doing i am obtaning the values but they are getting dispalyed 3 times     List<String> searchResults; status=(String)t.get("status");
    firstname=(String)t.get("first");
    lastname=(String)t.get("last"); searchResults=new ArrayList<String>();
 searchResults.add(status);
 searchResults.add(firstname);
 searchResults.add(lastname); 3 times for 3 values and 2 times for 2 values

Comment: :and one more doubt if the employee id is primary key and i want search independently then empid and empstatus seperately is this possible ? and suggest me some material for jpa and jsf itegeration app

Comment: I would propose you to create a separate question regarding JSF and related issues since I have no experience with it.

Comment: :and one more doubt if the employee id is primary key and i want search independently then empid and empstatus seperately is this possible ?